# BERT (Huggingface Transformer) - Get important features for class

Tags: text-classification, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

My goal is to get the most important features for each class in a text classification task.
I created the model, learner and predictor like this:

```
t = text.Transformer(model_name, maxlen=MAX_SEQ_LENGTH, class_names=emotions)
trn = t.preprocess_train(X_train.values, y_train.values)
val = t.preprocess_test(X_test.values, y_test.values)
model = t.get_classifier()
learner = ktrain.get_learner(model, train_data=trn, val_data=val, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
predictor = ktrain.get_predictor(learner.model, preproc=t)
```

Is there any way to get the top features like this:

[image]

(created for SVM)

Comment: Hello Amelie, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please try add your images on the body of the question.

Comment: @IsacMoura New users can't add images inline on their posts until they get 10 reputation.

Comment: [bertviz](https://github.com/jessevig/bertviz).